# Find a formula for the partial derivative in terms of the partial derivatives of $f$ and $g$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to find a formula for the partial derivative $\frac{\partial (g\circ f)_i}{\partial x_j}(x)$ in terms of the partial derivatives of $f$ and $g.$ My guess is
$$\frac{\partial (g\circ f)_i}{\partial x_j}(x)=\frac{\partial_{f_i}}{\partial f_j}(f(x))\cdot\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}(x)$$
Is my answer correct? If not, where's the problem?

Comment: Seems like you’re missing a $g$ in the RHS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to derive such things via differentials because the partial derivative notation can get in the way. As in Faraad’s answer, the key is the chain rule. In terms of differentials, this is $$\mathrm d(g\circ f)_{\mathbf x} = (\mathrm d g_{f(\mathbf x)})\circ(\mathrm df_{\mathbf x}).$$ In matrix form, $\mathrm d\phi$ is the Jacobian matrix—the matrix of partial derivatives of $\phi$, so ${\partial(g\circ f)_i\over\partial x_j}$ is just the $ij$-th element of $\mathrm d(g\circ f)$. Letting $x_i$ and $y_i$ be coordinates for the domains of $f$ and $g$ respectively, the definition of matrix multiplication gives $${\partial(g\circ f)_i \over \partial x_j}(\mathbf x) = \sum_k {\partial g_i \over \partial y_k}(f(\mathbf x))\cdot{\partial f_k \over \partial x_j}(\mathbf x).$$

Comment: Did you mean $\partial f_k$ in the denominator in the RHS? Also, if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m,$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^k,$ what is the range of $k$ in the summation? And if $y=f(x)$ and $z=g(y),$ you mean $\frac{\partial z_i}{\partial x_j}=\sum_k \frac{\partial z_i}{\partial y_k}\frac{\partial y_k}{\partial x_j}$?

Comment: 1) I suppose I do, although to me having $f$s in the denominator seems nonsensical. As I said, the notation just gets in the way :) 2) Since $\mathrm dg$ is a $k\times m$ matrix and $\mathrm df$ is a $m\times n$ matrix, the sum would range from $1$ to $m$. 3) Precisely.

Comment: Thanks! I just figured out the range of $k$ and my answer is the same as yours!

Answer (score 0):

Use chain rule.

$$\frac{\partial (g \circ f)}{\partial x_j}(x) = \nabla g|_{f(x)} \cdot \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} =  \left\langle \frac{\partial (g \circ f)_1}{\partial x_1}(x),..., \frac{( g \circ f)_n}{\partial{x_n}}(x) \right\rangle  \cdot \left\langle \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial{x_j}}(x),...,\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial{x_j}}(x) \right\rangle$$